# Trying to speed up load time on my website

Tags: javascript, html, performance, web, pagespeed

I am in the process of trying to speed up my HTML website and the first thing I have done is to reduce the images to the exact size that they are loaded into.

My PageSpeed Insight for desktop is 90 which I am very happy with but for mobile, it is 24, which isn't so good (was 19 before I did the images)! It says that I can save 4 seconds if I "remove unused JavaScript" but I haven't added any JavaScript to my website yet (only just taught myself HTML and CSS so moving onto JavaScript soon).

So I am wondering what this unused JavaScript is and how I can remove it if I wasn't the one to add it in there in the first place. Any other tips on how to speed up the website will be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: About scripts, your site has at least 27 script tags, most of these scripts come from google and some from twitter and facebook like timelines for example

Comment: They provide you with details for each suggestion https://web.dev/remove-unused-code/

Comment: Something you could do to improve the performance of your website, would be to use javascript to load images only when they are in the display window

Comment: To add to @AksJacoves comment, no need for JavaScript for that. You can you use the attribute `loading="lazy"` on your `<img />` tags to load images only when they are about to enter the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If by "speed up the page" you mean improve the performances of your website:

Changing the dimension of images don't necessary mean that they are "optimized for the web". You can find tools like https://optimage.app/ and information on the web on how to compress them.

You can use the inspector of your browser (Right-click on the page + Inspect) to do this :

1. Go to Network Tab, clear all logged requests then reload the page you will be able to see **which requests are the most time-expensives and maybe do something about it.**

[image]

2. Go to performance, start recording, reproduce the actions that you want to analyze

[image]

**(You can zoom in and out in the timeline and click on the element to have more details)**

Answer (score -1):

Delete all Javascript from your website

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).